# Codeigniter language file loading error in linux server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My codeigniter project working fine in local windows/xampp server, but when I upload to linux/LAMP server it shows this error

> Unable to load the requested language file:
>   language/English/form_validation_lang.php

`'language/english/form_validation_lang.php'` file is exits in relevant path,so how to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a generic issue offered by Code Ignitor. Take a look at your server logs, they may provide more information.

Also, take a look at the permissions of the file. It should be readable by the web server:

```
sudo chown apache:apache ./language/English/form_validation_lang.php
sudo chmod 770 ./language/English/form_validation_lang.php
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort., I tried that way. But same result. I changed folder namefron 'english' to 'English' , It works. This error i have only in linux